C# 32feet - The requested address is not valid in its context
I'm trying to connect my phone (Xiaomi) and my computer (asus) via bluetooth with C#. I get this error where it says the adress is not valid, here is the whole code
BluetoothClient client;
try
{
    client = new();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Turn your bluetooth on and try again.");
    return;
}

BluetoothDeviceInfo[] devices = client.DiscoverDevices();


Console.WriteLine("Bluetooth Devices: ");
for (int i = 0; i < devices.Count(); i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i + " - " + devices[i].DeviceName);
}

Console.Write("Choose the device to connect: ");
int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


BluetoothDeviceInfo device = devices[input];
Console.WriteLine("Device adress: " + device.DeviceAddress.ToString());


BluetoothAddress bluetoothAdress = new(device.DeviceAddress.ToByteArray());
BluetoothEndPoint endPoint = new(bluetoothAdress, BluetoothService.HumanInterfaceDevice);



try
{
    client.Connect(endPoint);
    
    if (client.Connected)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connected successfully to " + device.DeviceName);
    }else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connection failed.");
    }
    
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Could not connect: \n" + e.ToString());
}

And here is the error
Could not connect:
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10049): The requested address is not valid in its context. 684DB6B68F13:0000112400001000800000805f9b34fb
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
at InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.Msft.SocketBluetoothClient.Connect(BluetoothEndPoint remoteEP)
at InTheHand.Net.Sockets.BluetoothClient.Connect(BluetoothEndPoint remoteEP)

While BluetoothAddress is an unsigned long, you are creating a byte array from the BD_ADDR string, which is something completely different.
Instead you should use 32Feet's BluetoothAddress.Parse(), which should most likely work.
However, it would be simpler this way:
BluetoothEndPoint endPoint = new(device.DeviceAddress, BluetoothService.HumanInterfaceDevice);



At first i tried that method, it didnt work so i switched to the current version, so unluckily it doesnt work too.
The problem looks like it is caused by the address format but i dont know what to do. I added this line to the code
Console.WriteLine("Device adress: " + device.DeviceAddress.ToString());
And it looks like this:
684DB6B68F13
Instead of something like 00:00:00:00:00:00
And in the for loop where i log the device names, even if my phone's bluetooth is turned off, i can see it in the console.
